# Xamarin Android Player don't start my application

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I using Visual Studio 2017.
I install Xamarin Android Player, and start my app using Xamarin Android Player but my i see just emulator, my app is not runing. 
This is picture for this explanation:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check in `ConfigurationManager` is deploy option checked and you have to unlock simulator.

Comment: I don't understande, do you have a better explanation?

Comment: Restart your VS, deploy again, and don't forget to unlock your simulator.

Answer (score 0):

When You are running your app, if its run without any error and not open in your emulator, then you need to check deploy option is enable or not for your project.
To check deploy option follow below steps:
1- Open Build Menu -> Click on Configuration Manager one pop will open one popup like

http://prntscr.com/kel5xt

Check the checkbox of Deploy option is checked or not of YourProjectName.Android.